# xPath keep things in order

Tags: php, xpath

I'm doing some scraping

```
$headers = $xpath->query("//h4");
$scrapt = $xpath->query("//p[@class='location']");
$hrefs = $xpath->query("//h4/a/@href");

foreach($hrefs as $href){
echo $href->baseURI.$href->textContent;
echo "<br>";
}
foreach($headers as $header){
echo $header->nodeValue;
echo "<br>";
}
foreach($scrapt as $tweet){
echo $tweet->nodeValue;
echo "<br>";
}
```

I want to echo the results one at a time. So it would give me the URL then the header then the tweet. The only way I can think of doing this is to store the string into indexed arrays and then appending those indexes. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
$crawlers = [
  'hrefs' => $xpath->query("//h4/a/@href"),
  'headers' => $xpath->query("//h4"),
  'scrapt' => $xpath->query("//p[@class='location']"),
];

foreach ($crawlers as $type => $data) {
  var_dump($type);
  var_dump($data);
}
```